# How is a data set generated from a distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics

I am a mathematics student trying to learn some statistics on my own. In the context of many statistics books, the language "the data is generated from (or came from) certain distribution" appears a lot. I am trying to understand the exact meaning of this sentence. I will elborate my question with one specific example I came across in my reading.

In the book "the Elements of Statistical Learning" (ESL), the following classification example is discussed in section 2.3:
[image: Image credit "the Elements of Statistical Learning" Hastie, Tibshirani, Jerome]
The topic of the section is to illustrate the method of least squares and nearest neighbours through this example. In the discussion of which methods is better, the auther gave two scenarios, I quote:

"Scenario 1: The training data in each class were generated from bivariate
Gaussian distributions with uncorrelated components and different
means.

Scenario 2: The training data in each class came from a mixture of 10 low-
variance Gaussian distributions, with individual means themselves
distributed as Gaussian."

I will now express my confusion using the language of scenario 1:

Question 1: By the word "data"( or "training data"), do we mean the set of coordinates that is shown in the diagram and their color? In other words, "data" refers to the set {((`x_i,y_i`),`color_i`)} that is given in the diagram?

Question 2: How is this data generated from a bivariate Gaussian distribution? My thinking is the following:

A bivariate Gaussian distribution is a function that takes two inputs (indenpendent variables) and gives an output (a scalar). So to say the data above is generated from a bivariate Gaussian distribution is to say that I put all the coordinate of the points in the diagram into the function, and use the function output to determine the color of the points (btw, the rule is that coloar blue is 0 meaning function output value less than 0.5, and otherwise orange). If this is the exact generating process, then my question is that why are the points in the above diagram so randomly positioned? Why can't we input a set of orderly points into the equation (i.e. Gaussian distribution) and color them accordingly? Say we can pick the set of points {(x,y) | x, y `$\in \ \mathbb{Z}$`}? (It would make the diagram much prettier at least.)

If the generating process is not what I proposed to be, then what does it mean for the data above to be generated from a bivaraite Gaussian distribution?

Question 3: Senario 2 confuses me entirely, how is one set of data generated from 10 different distributions?

It is my first time posting a question here, so feel free to tell if there is anything I did wrong or inappropriate. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You might be interested in section 4 and appendix A of this [tutorial paper from the 2008 Winter Simulation Conference](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc07papers/007.pdf).  It gives a quick summary and some examples of the mechanisms used to computationally generate distributions.

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks a lot! @pjs

Comment: Relevant: Devroye, L. (1986). [*Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation*](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html). Springer Verlag.

Comment: On random number generation (per the title in particular) - numerous posts on site address sampling from distributions; univariate and multivariate, discrete and continuous. A few searches will turn up *many* dozens of useful answers. The multivariate Gaussian case or bivariate special case is addressed many times over (your second question), as is generating from mixture distributions (per your third question). If you remove the parts that are *already* comprehensively dealt with, there only seems to be question 1 left. This is why we avoid multi-question "questions", by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be several kinds of situations. For example, (i) naturally occurring data that are known from experience or predicted from theory to follow a particular distribution, and (ii) data artificially generated using rules that match specifications of the distribution.

*Naturally occurring.* suppose the data you show may have come from surveys or tests administered to various subjects. The may come close to matching a particular distribution.
Heights of groups of humans are often assumed to be normally distributed. *Strictly speaking,* this cannot be precisely correct because any truly normal distribution has to include the possibility (even if extremely small) of negative values and it is meaningless to
speak of a person with a negative height. [See Note.] Weights of people are sometimes
treated as if they are normal, but that is often a fanciful assumption. Test
scores may be naturally approximately normal or questions on tests may be
manipulated to give nearly normal total scores.

Data that are approximately bivariate normal may be heights and weights of
people; there may be a positive association because taller people may tend to weigh more. (This often works best for distinct groups of people such as female swimmers or male wrestlers.)

*Artificially generated.* Statistical software programs often have procedures
for 'sampling' or 'generating' data that behave as if they were random samples from a particular distribution. For example in R, the procedure 'rnorm' will
sample from a specified normal distribution. If people in a particular
population have heights nearly normally distributed with mean 68in and standard deviation 3.5in, then we might imitate a sample of 50 such 'heights', summarize them, and make a boxplot of them, using
the program below:

```
set.seed(903)
x = round(rnorm(50, 68, 3.5))

 summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  60.00   66.00   68.00   68.56   71.00   79.00 

stripchart(x, pch="|")
```

[image]

These 'heights' are not exactly normal because they have been rounded to
the nearest integer. Nevertheless they 'pass' a Shapiro-Wilk normality test
with a P-value $0.18 > 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
shapiro.test(x)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x
W = 0.96726, p-value = 0.1787
```

*Note:* Someone has commented that one will never see a
negative value sampling from a population distributed $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=68, \sigma=3.5).$ As a practical matter, that is probably true, but the probability of a negative value is positive, even if very small, as computed in R below. To avoid negative values, one could use a normal distribution truncated to have only positive values (no longer precisely normal). In practice, this is seldom done because results to four places are not changed.

```
pnorm(0, 68, 3.5)
[1] 2.212535e-84  # very tiny, but not 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand why the coordinates cannot be freely chosen. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

> So to say the data above is generated from a bivariate Gaussian distribution is to say that I put all the coordinate of the points in the diagram into the function

That would imply that the coordinates were given and then afterwards put through a deterministic process. I do not have that particular book but I am quite positive that something else is meant: The coordinates of the points are the result of a random process. (And as the authors had no better method at hand they were produced by a pseurorandom process in their computers, probably some R 'function').

As I am not a mathematician I do not know appropriate notation. I'll do what we do often here, I'll take the computer language R for notation. If in R I say

```
MASS::mvrnorm(1, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,.5, .5, 1),nrow=2))
```

it will answer with two coordinates of a random point

```
[1] -0.09439794  1.52760301
```

And if I do the same again I will get two different coordinates and there is no practical way to predict those. However, if I do that time and time again the data will be a random sample from a certain distribution, in this case

[image: A point cloud resempbling a multivariate normal distribution. Every point is the result of a random experiment]

To take a sample from 10 different distributions just means to perform that process with ten probability density distributions and then build the union of the randomly drawn points.

We could start producing something like the graphic above as in

```
blue <- MASS::mvrnorm(100, mu = c(1.5,-1), Sigma = matrix(c(1,.5, .6, 1),nrow=2))
orange <- MASS::mvrnorm(100, mu = c(0,1), Sigma = matrix(c(1,-.3, -.3, 1),nrow=2))

plot(orange[,1], orange[,2], col = "orange", xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim=c(-2, 3))
points(blue[,1], blue[,2], col = "blue")
```

and get

[image]

Comment: I was confused a bit with your answers at first, but combing with the answer from BruceET I understand now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was about to add a third part to my answer along these lines. But this is fine.

Comment: @Zhengyuan.Dong Great. If it was useful consider clicking on the up-arrow to upvote it. You can do that with BruceET's answer as well - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Bernhard I did do that but it requires me to have 15 or more reputation which I don't for now.

Comment: Alright, that should have improved by now.. ;-)